# How to target nearest class within a container using jquery?

Tags: jquery, nextuntil

I want to target the nearest class and stop on targeting other class elements if it's the last item to be read on that part. Here is what I am trying to achieve.

[image]

The `.is-child` class will show if the `.parent` class is clicked and only the nearest class will be shown. I already tried using `.next()` method but it will only show 1 `.is-child` element per click

Here is my code:

```
    jQuery('li.current.parent').click(function(){
         jQuery(this).next('.is-child').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

I also tried using `.nextAll` but it will show all of the `.is-child` element.

```
    jQuery('li.current.parent').click(function(){
         jQuery('.is-child').nextAll('.is-child').css('display', 'block');
    });
```

Comment: Right, and what have you tried?

Comment: @Utkanos Currently using this code http://codejaw.com/r4wrrxi

Comment: Also tried `closest()` method but I can't make it work.

Comment: What's with the down vote? Is there any part that I didn't explained well?

Comment: Downvote due to no attempt shown (initially), and no code in the question. Please add the code to the question.

Comment: I already said that I tried using `.next()` and `.closest` method but it will only show one element per click. Will update my question then

Comment: The second is almost there `jQuery(this).nextUntil('.parent').css('display', 'block');`

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza - cool, no worries - retracted :)

Comment: @Utkanos Awesome! Will you please put it on the answer for this question so that I can mark it?

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza Is that `jQuery(this).nextUntil('.parent').css('display', 'block');` the answer?

Comment: @AlonEitan yep it's the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select the elements using [.nextUntil](https://api.jquery.com/nextUntil/) - This will select all the element from `$(this)` until the specified selector (Not including `$(this)` AND that element that match to the selector):

```js
$(function() {
  jQuery('li.current.parent').click(function(){
    jQuery(this).nextUntil('.parent').css('background-color', 'red');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="current parent">click here</li>
  <li class="is-child">hi</li>
  <li class="is-child">hi</li>
  <li class="is-child">hi</li>
  <li class="parent">bye</li>
</ul>
```